# Is there a easy way to get commonly used symbols without leaving the site?

Tags: discussion

When writing a question or answer there are some commonly used symbols or typesetting styles that are missing. The two that come to mind are the degree symbol (°) for temperatures and refractometer readings, and subscript (e.g. CO<sub>2</sub>) which often come up on the site.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't know this before writing the question - to get the degree symbol, I googled and copy/pasted the symbol from text in the page. There's a much quicker way:

- degree is `&deg;`  (°)
- subscript is `<sub></sub>` around the text. E.g. `CO<sub>2</sub>` makes CO<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Now we know it's possible, the trick will be remembering to use it!

Comment: I printed these out and taped them to my monitor. Also, Alt+0176 gives you the ° symbol on a Windows PC, but there is no Alt code for <sub>2</sub>.